# Esper - Aggegation by partitioning

Tags: esper

I am new to Esper. I am stuck at the implementation of this problem.

The input sensor event data is of the following format: (id, time, value, intensity)
I want to do aggregation of value for each id and intensity.

So, the output data should be of the format: id, start_time, end_time, aggregated value, intensity (high, low, medium)
where start_time is the time when the analysis is started and end_time is the time when analysis ended and analysis is done on sliding window of 11 seconds.
For the input data:

1, t1, x1, i1
1, t2, x1, i1
1, t3, x2, i1
1, t4, x3, i1
1, t5, x5, i2
1, t6, x6, i1
2, t7, x7, i1
The output will look like:
1, t1, t1, v1, i1
1, t1, t2, v2, i1
1, t1, t3, v3, i1
1, t1, t4, v4, i1
1, t5, t5, v5, i2
1, t6, t6, v6, i1
2, t7, t7, v7, i1 and so on.

In the result set we can see that data are grouped by id and intensity, but once a different (id, intensity) appears analysis for that stops. 
How can I obtain the result in this format? 
I tried to use prev() function, but that does not work, because I have no idea how many events will be there.
Please suggest me what I should try to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The "prev" function can tell you when a previous group stops. You could have the "prev" generate an indicator that a sequence ended. For example an "insert into Trigger select field from Event where prev(field) <> field" would generate a Trigger event when "prev" encountered changing fields. The trigger event can then be used to perform the analysis and maybe remove the rows. A named window could be used to store the relevant rows until analysis is done.